# PayPal RestApi get UserInfo

Tags: java, paypal, oauth-2.0

Paypal login workflow is https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/lipp/oic_flowchart.png

In web application our guys did 2 steps from previous picture and put to database authtoken and refreshToken for customers. 
I want later get UserInfo (step 3)

Documentation  says that we can get userInfo with GET request with Autorization using accessToken.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#get-user-information

I tried:

1. I get access token by App_ID and Secret_Key.
   If I put it to GET request i take userInfo for owner paypal application. I cannot put customerID(user_id) to this GET  request as params.
2. If I put customer accessToken to GET request I get unauthorized error, because customer accessToken is old.
   I need to refresh it with refreshToken, but I cannot do it.
   Server answer is Error code : 400 with response : {"error_description":"Unable to refresh access token","error":"invalid_request","correlation_id":"fee0c71c02cda","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"}

Why I cannot refresh accesstoken? (I didn't find any answer in forum)

Or maybe I cannot get User information later and we should do it immediately after step 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose step 2, i just try valid accessToken from User. And it works.
But  If you want refresh token you should send request using autorization by right client_id and client-secret.